# How to hide the custom Header Component on other screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

How can I hide this custom header component on sub-screens in the tab navigators using the getRoutName function in my code below

I created a prop with a name visible

I want to implement how I'm hiding the tabs with the getRoutName function with the custom Header component

Ive tried using the useRoute hook to get the current route and it keeps on printing an error

```
import {Platform, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import {
  getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute,
  useNavigation,
  useRoute,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

import GlobalConfig from '../Config/GlobalConfig';

import Header from '../Components/Header';
import AppSafeArea from '../Components/AppSafeArea';

const global = GlobalConfig[GlobalConfig.CURRENT_APP];
const tabs = global.tabs;
const colors = global.colors;
const currentTab = global.tabType;
const tabTypeName = global.tabTypeName;

const TabsNavigator = () => {
  const [isIcon, setIsIcon] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // console.log(navigation.getCurrentRoute());
  useEffect(() => {
    tabTypeName === 'TopTabs' ? setIsIcon(true) : setIsIcon(false);
  });
  return (
    <>
      <AppSafeArea />
      <Header
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        // visible={}
      />
      <currentTab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.tertiary,
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: colors.white,
          tabBarStyle: {
            ...styles.tabbar,
          },
        }}>
        {tabs.map((tab, index) => {
          return (
            <currentTab.Screen
              key={index}
              name={tab.tabName}
              component={tab.tabComponent}
              options={({route}) => ({
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarIconStyle: {display: isIcon ? 'none' : 'flex'},
                tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (
                  <tab.tabIcon width={20} height={20} fill={color} />
                ),
                tabBarStyle: {
                  display: getRoutName(route),
                  ...styles.tabbar,
                },

                tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 13},
              })}
            />
          );
        })}
      </currentTab.Navigator>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabbar: {
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
});

export default TabsNavigator;

const excludedRoutes = [
  'LiveStream',
  'AboutChurch',
  'PrayerRequest',
  'ShareTestimony',
  'DevotionalMessages',
  'CheckInHistory',
  'MakeDonation',
  'Pledge',
  'GivingHistory',
  'SavedPosts',
  'AboutTheDeveloper',
  'MomoPay',
  'CardDetails',
  'CardPayment',
  'EditProfile',
  'MakeRequest',
  'RequestForm',
  'FeedPreview',
  'MoreSettings',
  'AddMomoNumber',
];

const getRoutName = route => {
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);

  if (routeName && excludedRoutes.some(route => routeName.includes(route))) {
    return 'none';
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your exact code but you can hide the header on any screen by using following hook in the screen code.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
          headerShown: false
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You see there is no header component in materialTopTab navigation so I had to create my own custom header